# Change Bootstrap 2.0.4 responsive navbar width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a Site using Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.4 + bootstraps responsive.css. What I don't know is: Is it possible to have a logo appearing at the top left of the site and the navbar appearing on the right of the logo (but fixed at top)? While changing Sizes, the Logo should then appear on top of the navbar.

Would be really nice to get an answer for I haven't found anything helpful yet.

Greetings,
Dominik

edit: Here's a picture describing what I want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/HX3ZM.png

Logo on the left, then navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I used the fixed navbar, which didn't work as expected. You have to use a static navbar. Then you could just use the row / scaffolding system from bootstrap.

Example code for a logo left from the navbar:

```
   <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <p><img src="/sites/img/your_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="responsive-logo"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
              <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="icon-user"></i> Username
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end navbar -->
    </div><!-- end span8 -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
```

To make my Logo responsive, I added the following css rules:

```
  .responsive-logo {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: 0;
padding-top: 10px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure—you will need to re-structure your document to place (for example) a div with the span4 class above the navbar.

Below that, have the navbar code and remove the branding elements (which usually house your logo). My assumption leads me to believe you want something like this:

[image: Re-designed]

If you can be a bit more specific about what you want, and/or provide the relevant parts (HTML) of your site, I can likely give some more direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just made a picture which describes what i want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/HX3ZM.png The Logo should appear on the left with a sidebar below, and on the right (the blue thingy ;) ) the sidebar with content below. When resizing to a very low viewport, the logo should just appear on top of the sidebar (but this is not the main problem). I don't know exactly how to position the logo on the left of the sidebar, but in the same "row".